# "She is said to be a thief" - is that the correct way to form the passive voice of "People say that she is a thief"?

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

I'm sorry I couldn't find a proper English title for the topic I'm going to ask you about. I'll give examples:

> People say that she is a thief.
> It is said (that) she is a thief.
> **She is said to be a thief.**

I think I got it all right except a Perfect Continuous Infinitive. - e.g.  'to have been doing'.

Could you please give examples as I did above and explain the usage? Unfortunately, I've been searching in all sources available to me, but I couldn't find neither examples, nor clear explanation.

Comment: Your two sentences have nothing to do with "to have been doing".

Comment: _She is said to have been doing something_ is a decent example. But it bears no relationship to your examples.

Comment: “Have been doing” doesn’t seem to apply to the situation you have illustrated in your examples. That is, the perfect continuous infinitive does not apply in the same situations as your examples. You cannot say “People say that she has been being a thief.” Please clarify what kind of usage you’re asking about!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I try to interpret what you are trying to ask: how a sentence like the following can be converted to other forms.

'She is said *to have been doing* something.'

If we want to convert it **back** to the form of your original examples, we could say

> People say that she has been doing something.

> It is said that she has been doing something.